# How to check if a key exists in a response object in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am fetching data from server after submitting data via angular2. This is my submitPost code:-

```
submitPost()
{        
      this._adminLogin.postAdminLogin(this.adminLoginmodel).subscribe(
          data => {
                this.responseStatus = data;
                if(this.responseStatus.status == 1)
                {
                  this.router.navigate(['admin/dashboard'])
                }
                else
                {
                  alert('Login Error');
                }
              },
          err => {
                console.log(err)
              },
          () => {}
      ); 
      this.status = true;       
}
```

This is the response structure I am getting:-

```
For Error: {"status":0,"message":"An error occured while logging in","error":""}
For Success: {"status":1,"message":"Login Success","error":""}
```

However, this LoC is causing some trouble:-

```
if(this.responseStatus.status == 1)
```

While pressing `ng serve --host` from commandline to run the project, the compilation is getting failed. Here is the message I am getting:-

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the `data` object of `any` type or set an appropriate type for `data`. Setting `any` will just turn off compiler checking for it.

```
.subscribe((data: any) =>
```

or

```
.subscribe((data: MyResponse) =>
```

where `MyResponse` is something like

```
interface MyResponse {
   status: number;
   message: string;
}
```